# Dynamically read and filter an XML file

Tags: objective-c, xml, macos, cocoa, xml-parsing

iTunes exports an XML file at

```
/Users/username/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music Library.xml
```

My app needs to read this file.
It works pretty well with my library of 2200 songs, but for larger libraries it

1. Loads all into the RAM
2. Takes up to 10 seconds for starting up

I need to dynamically read this xml file, and be able to iterate though it at the same time.

Any suggestions, sample code, references, tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using a DOM-based (NSXMLDocument?) approach to load your iTunes library.
This would explain the memory consumption and slow startup behavior.

To avoid loading the whole document into RAM at once, you should switch to a SAX parser and skip elements that you are not interested in.
Cocoa's built in SAX Parser is [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which allows you to sequentially read and filter elements by conforming to [NSXMLParserDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSXMLParserDelegate).

As you seem to build a iTunes related app:
Apple recently [published documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/iTunesLibrary/Reference/iTunesLibraryFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012886) for the now public iTunesLibrary.framework.

Comment: Until now I've been loading everything into a `NSDictionary`.
I'll take a look at `NSXMLParser`.
The **iTunesLibrary.framework** sounds good as well, however it's only available for iTunes 11 or higher.